# Hudson Plug-in help for making build steps optional

Tags: hudson

I have hudson job which will do both Build (ant) / deployment(shell commands) tasks in one job; is there a way, i can make deployment task optional so that i can run my build step on schedule basis and run deployment step on-demand basis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

1. Just separate jobs
2. Make parametrized job (see http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Parameterized+Build) and add validation before deployment job, e.g.

   ```
   if [ -e "$deploy" ] ; then
       #deployment
   fi
   ```